# Wordpress store date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, datetime

I'm a newbie in php and Wordpress. I'm trying to create a script that will store data into a custom table in wordpress. I want the script to store the current date and time in the mysql database. I have created a column in the Mysql table with it's data type set to `DATETIME` but when I try to insert data into the table, the current date is not being shown. Waht might be the problem? My script is shown below.

```
    $wpdb->insert($table,array('account_id' => $account_id, 'billing_first_name'=>$first_name,'billing_last_name' => $last_name, 'feature_level' => 'FreeAccount','created_at'=> date("Y-m-d, h:i a"),'billing_interval' => "Manual"));
```

Comment: -1 for "You're code is not working." without thinking on your own…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is an issue with the date format you are passing in the query.

Considering created_at as the column in MySql having `DATETIME` format, you should pass created_at in the correct format. I think `DATETIME` field accepts date and time in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Can you try with this query:

```
$wpdb->insert($table,array('account_id' => $account_id, 'billing_first_name'=>$first_name,'billing_last_name' => $last_name, 'feature_level' => 'FreeAccount','created_at'=> date("Y-m-d h:i:s"),'billing_interval' => "Manual"));
```

Here the only change in the query is the create_at field value you are passing it to MySql.

```
date("Y-m-d h:i:s")
```

If created_at is not the `DATETIME` field in db, and you have another column that you set as `DATETIME` and you want to get it updated when you insert a record, then change the db structure to automatically update the `DATETIME` field on update. Set Default as `CURRENT TIMESTAMP`. So even if you don't pass value to that field it will automatically get updated.

Hope this is what you want.
 :)

Comment: Try enable WP_DEBUG true in wp-config.php and check what is the error or try running the query in PhpMyadmin

Comment: You told this was not working.. What was the issue?? Can you please let me know

Comment: Someone had misconfigured the MySQL server. Thanks it works now.